# Como enlazar directorios en cmake y acceder desde la implementacion mediante /directorio/fichero.h en lugar de /fichero.h

Tags: c++, cmake

Tengo un proyecto con la siguiente estructura:

```
-src
--logging
---ILogger.h
---ClogLogger.cpp
---ClogLogger.h
--CMakeList.txt
```

Y con el siguiente CMakeList.txt:

```
...

include_directories(logging)

set(COMMON_UTILS_SRCS
    logging/ILogger.h
    logging/ClogLogger.h
    logging/ClogLogger.cpp
    )

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${COMMON_UTILS_SRCS})

...
```

Me gustaría saber como debería añadir la librería para que en la implementación logging/ClogLogger.cpp pueda hacer:

```
#include "logging/ClogLogger.h"
```

En lugar de:

```
#include "ClogLogger.h"
```

Comment: Prueba `include_directories( "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}" )`.

Comment: No, eso no ha funcionado

Comment: ¿ Que significa `eso no ha funcionado` ? Ten presente que el que localice el archivo de una forma no implica que no lo haga de la otra. Con la jerarquía que tienes, lo va a encontrar siempre simplemente poniendo el nombre. Con lo que te puse, también debería encontrarlo poniendo `directorio/nombre.h`

Comment: Añadiendo ese include en el CMake no he podido compilar el proyecto, no encuentra la ruta de los includes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lugar de:

```
include_directories(logging)
```

Podrías agregar la misma carpeta del **CMakeLists.txt** a los directorios de inclusión. Así la sintaxis `<logging/archivo.h>` será compatible:

```
include_directories(.)
```

El punto se utiliza para referirse a ella.

Answer (score -1):

Si en el .cpp indicas:

```
#include "logging/ClogLogger.h"
```

Se va a buscar el header en el directorio logging, relativo a la ubicación del cpp.

Tendrías que mover el cpp y modificar el CMakeList.txt. Por ejemplo:

```
-src
--ClogLogger.cpp // <- fuera de la carpeta logging
--logging
---ILogger.h
---ClogLogger.h
--CMakeList.txt
```

Y entonces:

```
include_directories(logging)

set(COMMON_UTILS_SRCS
    logging/ILogger.h
    logging/ClogLogger.h
    ClogLogger.cpp  // <- Ojo Cambio aquí
    )

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${COMMON_UTILS_SRCS})
```

Comment: Hola jCres, gracias por tu respuesta. La idea es mantener la estructura de ficheros. Esto luego se compila como una libreria de conan en un proyecto bastante grande

Comment: Si miras [aqui](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-include-directive-c-cpp?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-170) parece que puedes crear un header dummy en el directorio padre, e incluirlo en el CmakeList.txt

Comment: Podrias ser un poco mas espeficífico? No entiendo muy bien si debería crear un fichero includes.h o algo similar para incluir ahí los ficheros del subdirectorio.

Comment: Si entiendo bien la referencia que te he compartido en teoría puedes crear un header con nombre a tu elección: por ejemplo auxiliar.h en el mismo directorio del cmakelist. Entonces añadir auxiliar al cmakelists dentro de la directiva set().

Comment: No me gusta mucho para luego realizar los test, pero he de admitir que la idea funciona. Muchas gracias.